# reverse fibonacci series generation using recursion

Tags: python-3.x

Reverse generation of fibonacci series without any loops.

Can this be done using a single recursive call.
input= 6
output= 5,3,2,1,1,0

```
def fibonacii(n):
    if n==1 or n==2:
        return 1
    k=fibonacii(n-1)+fibonacii(n-2)
    return k

def fibonaciiseries(n):
    if (n==1):
        print(0)
    else:
        q=fibonacii(n-1)
        print(q)
        return fibonaciiseries(n-1)
```

Comment: I don't think you can generate Fibonacci numbers in reverse. You must first generate and store them in a list (or some other data structure) and then reverse that list.

Comment: See this code. We could do this without any list.

Comment: Great! But you're still generating them in ascending order and implicitly storing them in some data structure (the call stack in this case).

Comment: Well That's true. But it sure does the job.

Comment: You can now close the question by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using a single recursive function without any array or loops.

```
def fibonacci(n,a=-1,b=1,count=0):

if(count<n):
    fibonacci(n,b,a+b,count+1)
    print(a+b)
else:
    return
```

Calling the function fibonacci(6) will then print the first 6 numbers in reverse order.